# Как вывести данные с объекта  ?

Tags: javascript

Нужно с помощью **console.log ()** вывести из объекта **"data"** данные в соответствии массива **"digCnt"**

Например, в первая цифра в массиве 2 значит нужно вывести данные c объекта "1 : { 2: здесь должен быть текст 2}"

```
var digCnt = [2,1,4,5];
var data = {
    1: {
        1: 'здесь должен быть текст 1',
        2: 'здесь должен быть текст 2',
        3: 'здесь должен быть текст 3',
        4: 'здесь должен быть текст 4',
        5: 'здесь должен быть текст 5',
        6: 'здесь должен быть текст 6',
    },
    2: {
        0: 'здесь должен быть текст 0',
        1: 'здесь должен быть текст 1', 
        2: 'здесь должен быть текст 2', 
        3: 'здесь должен быть текст 3', 
        4: 'здесь должен быть текст 4', 
        5: 'здесь должен быть текст 5',          
    },
    3: {
        0: 'здесь должен быть текст 0',
        1: 'здесь должен быть текст 1', 
        2: 'здесь должен быть текст 2', 
        3: 'здесь должен быть текст 3', 
        4: 'здесь должен быть текст 4', 
        5: 'здесь должен быть текст 5',          
    },
    4: {
        1: 'здесь должен быть текст 1', 
        2: 'здесь должен быть текст 2', 
        3: 'здесь должен быть текст 3', 
        4: 'здесь должен быть текст 4', 
        5: 'здесь должен быть текст 5',          
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В цикле обходите массив digCnt и выводите нужные значения.

Примерно так:

```
for(var i = 0; i < digCnt.length; i++)
{
    console.log(data[i + 1][digCnt[i]]);
}
```

**Пример: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPYK8/)**